# Excel convert comma seperated downwards WITH other columns

Tags: excel, transpose

I'm trying to do this: 
[image: Sample data]

The long way to do this:
Highlight 1 cell in B. Text to columns. Copy all the cells in the output. Paste using transpose. Then drag col A to fill in the blanks downwards.

There must be an easier way :(

Comment: You can split the single cells, then looping through the resulting array and create a new line for each element.

Comment: Yes it is called VBA.  You will need to code a routine that does this.

Comment: You could do it with one or two helper columns using formulae but it's true the VBA would just be a few lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claimed in the comments that you could also do this by formula with a couple of helper columns and wanted to see (a) if that was true and (b) how difficult it would be to do. The answers were (a) yes, just about and (b) very (although there are people out there who are more skilled in complex formulae than I am).

Here is the result:-

[image]

So the helper columns are just like the i's and j's in the VBA where

```
Column C (i) is source row
Column D (j) is string number within source row
```

But to achieve this you need some long formulae.

C7 and C8 are just hard-coded to 1.

In D8:-

```
=IF(C7="","",IF(D7<LEN(INDEX(B$2:B$4,C7))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(B$2:B$4,C7),",",""))+1,D7+1,IF(C7=ROWS($B$2:$B$4),"",1)))
```

In C8:-

```
=IF(D8="","",IF(D8>D7,C7,C7+1))
```

In B7:-

```
=IF(C7="","",MID(","&INDEX(B$2:B$4,C7)&",",FIND("<",SUBSTITUTE(","&INDEX(B$2:B$4,C7)&",",",","<",D7))+1,FIND(">",SUBSTITUTE(","&INDEX(B$2:B$4,C7)&",",",",">",D7+1))-FIND("<",SUBSTITUTE(","&INDEX(B$2:B$4,C7)&",",",","<",D7))-1))
```

In A7:-

```
=IF(C7="","",INDEX($A$2:$A$4,C7))
```

It is semi-dynamic because any changes to the source cells will be reflected in the destination cells. It is tied to a fixed source range $B$2:$B$4, but could be changed to work with a variable source range fairly easily. I haven't assumed that the numbers all have 7 digits, but if you did it would simplify the formula in B7.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered how the VBA would compare with doing it with formulae.

Here is a sample VBA and it is pretty short even though there might be smarter ways of doing it:-

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SplitRows()

Dim a() As String
Dim r1, r2 As Range
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Set r1 = Range("A2:B4")
Set r2 = Range("A7:B1000")
j = 1

For i = 1 To r1.Rows.Count
    a = Split(r1.Cells(i, 2), ",")
    For k = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      r2.Cells(j, 1) = r1.Cells(i, 1)
      r2.Cells(j, 2) = a(k)
      j = j + 1
    Next k
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try. In the meantime, I've written a php script to process this data for me. It would be great to do it within XLS though, so will certainly give this a try (just need to figure out how to use VBA in XLS)

Comment: It's just Alt-F11 from an Excel sheet then Insert Module and paste in the code: F5 to run.